# How to assign a data source to time range control in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to create a time range control to control a time series chart in Data Studio. As it shown in [official video by Google Analytics](https://youtu.be/Jafy-CB148k?t=87) on managing of the data range control element should be a possibility to add a data source(s) - which seems to be obligatory - how should the control element know, what data it should control?

The data source input looks like on the screenshot:

[image]

But in "my" Data Studio is this possibility not available - look at screenshot:

[image]

Not the tab "Basic", not the input for the data source.

The youtube video is from the year 2016 - the GUI of Data Studio changed some times - but i can still not found, how to add a data source to time range control.

I tested it with Chrome and Firefox with three different accounts - always the same lack of this.

Could somebody point me to the right place where i find adding of data source to time range control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project, select **Page** on the navigation bar then select **Current Page Setting**.